# Unexpected behavior retrofit + coroutines

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2, kotlin-coroutines

I have this services call, the itemNum is: 15 by default.

```
@GET("curated")
suspend fun getCurated(@Query("per_page") itemNum: Int, @Query("page") numPage: Int): Response<List<Photo>>
```

And here is where the services are call, now im only retrieve the last 15 element of the list because the issue, but  is a temporal fix. the response result store all the elements of the call.

```
    suspend fun getCuratedFotos(queryString: String?, pageNumber: Int, resetLit:Boolean): OperationResult {

    if (resetLit) {
        listFotos.let { listFotos.clear() }
    }

    val response: Response<List<Foto>> = if (queryString != null) {
        fotosApi.getSearch(queryString, AppConstants.ITEM_NUMBER, pageNumber)
    } else {
        fotosApi.getCurated(AppConstants.ITEM_NUMBER, pageNumber)
    }

    return if (response.isSuccessful) {
        if (response.body().isNullOrEmpty()) {
            OperationResult(false, "Result are empty", null)
        } else {
            response.body()?.let { listFotos.addAll(it.takeLast(AppConstants.ITEM_NUMBER)) }
            OperationResult(true, "", listFotos)
        }
    } else {
        OperationResult(false, "Error in network request", null)
    }
}
```

This returns a response object with a list of 15 items, the problem i am facing is in the first call to services returns the first 15 items from page 1, but in the second call it returns a list of 30 items the first 15 + 15 new.

Hope the list only contains the 15 items from each call.
Somehow Retrofit  stack the results.

This behavior starts when coroutines are implemented, before it works as I expected

I need only the 15 elementos of the current call, someone know how achieve that?

Here i copy the debug panel where you see the call parameters and the result elements.

[image]

Comment: Can you post the code where you make the call to `getCurated`? My suspicion is that if you are receiving only 15 items the first time you call it and 30 items the next time you call it you're using the wrong value for `itemNum` or `numPage` on the subsequent call.

Comment: No, i debug the calls and the numbers of page and itemNum are correct, but if you want see i add the rest of the code of the call.

Comment: Retrofit doesn't do any stacking of the results. Without more context it will be difficult to answer this question.

Comment: Are you sure the problem isn't on the API side? Do you get the same results with Postman or Curl?

Comment: I copy more details in the question. Tell Me if you can see any more.

Comment: Nop the api works fine, the problem begins when start using coroutines.

Comment: I guess it must be something about the implementation of coroutines in retrofit.

Answer (score 1):

Seems you are adding the new results to the end of whatever is already in the list:

```kotlin
response.body()?.let { listFotos.addAll(it.takeLast(AppConstants.ITEM_NUMBER)) }
OperationResult(true, "", listFotos)
```

You should return a new list instead:

```kotlin
OperationResult(true, "", response.body()?.takeLast(AppConstants.ITEM_NUMBER))
```

Comment: I making a new list of the last 15 element of the response of retrofit. That is for the issue.